# How can I insert the reference ID of one table into another table?

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I want to add the data by use javascript but i think i can get the id from reference table that why i can't add the data. Please Help.

This my view page.

```
<div  id="tbl_add_new">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $this->uri->segment(3);?>">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 50%; text-align: right;">Date :</td>
            <td style="width: 50%; text-align: left;"><input type="text" id="date" name="date" placeholder="Date" value="" class="frm_text_full"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 50%; text-align: right;">No.Doc :</td>
            <td style="width: 50%; text-align: left;"><input type="text" rows="2" cols="40" id="no_doc" name="no_doc" value="" placeholder="No.Doc" class="frm_text_full"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <a href="javascript:;" id="add_new_code" class="frm_button" >Save</a>
</div>
```

This my Controller

```
function add_lines(){
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $date = $this->input->post('date');
    $no_doc = $this->input->post('no_doc');

    $data = array(
            'id_lines_code' => $this->m_stock->generate_id(),
            'id'  => $id,
            'date'  => $date,
            'no_doc' => $no_doc
    );
    $this->m_stock->add_detail($data);
    $data['lines'] = $this->m_stock->get_detail($id);
    $this->load->view('v_line_stocks',$data);
}
```

This my model for show the line in reference id

```
function get_lines($id){
    $result = array();
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tbl_lines_code');
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $this->db->order_by('date', 'ASC');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->result() > 0) {
        $result = $query->result();
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Could you add more details to your question? Where do you call `get_lines`, what is your proccess flow?

Comment: get lines is get all detail in id in the page can add the new data and show all detail in the page too.